# How to search </string> in vim?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vi

I want to search  in vim,

```
/</string>
```

but it didn't work, how to do can exactly match "`</string>`"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An alternative to escaping the slash (`\/`) is to use the backward-search: `?</string>` (and navigating to next matches with `N` instead of `n`).

Answer (score 12):

Escape the "/" with a backslash:

```
/<\/string>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to search for a literal value, the \V "very no magic" prefix can be helpful. When specified, every character except \ is treated as its literal value, so in your case /\V would match exactly what you want. I often find it more readable than interspersing backslashes through the pattern.

You can look at `:help magic` for more information.

Comment: This was helpful for when a string contained single quotes

Answer (score 4):

Try to search by escaping the`/` by adding `\` before the `/`.

```
Eg: /<\/string>
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Use **:s** instead. Eg.

```
%:s:/home/johndoe/.git::gc
```

This examples searches for the pathname (g for greedy) and replaces with nothing, if the user confirms (c for confirm)
help :s (help on substitute) does not tell that one may use any character to separate search and replace strings. It doesn't have to be a slash /